# How to use material switch with shinydashboard [R]

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I know I am missing something obvious, but for some reason I'm not able to get a material switch to do anything in a shiny app, using shinydashboard.

I want to use it in the sidebar, to activate another input. However, with the code below, although the switch appears, it doesn't do anything.

I think the key is probably in the condition of the conditionalPanel...

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("shinyWidgets")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(materialSwitch(inputId = "check", 
        label = h4("View by options")),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.check == TRUE",
        awesomeRadio(inputId = "options", label = NULL, choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
                           selected = c("A"))))

body <- dashboardBody()

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
                sidebar,
                body
                )

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this is `javascript` conditional so it doesnt know what `TRUE` is as its an `R` evaluation, change this to `true`

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("shinyWidgets")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(materialSwitch(inputId = "check", 
                                           label = h4("View by options")),
                            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.check == true",
                                             awesomeRadio(inputId = "options", label = NULL, choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
                                                          selected = c("A"))))

body <- dashboardBody()

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
                    sidebar,
                    body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```